# Como chamar construtores com argumentos?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, parâmetros, construtor

Como definir os valores do construtor na classe principal pelo `Scanner`
em um construtor assim?.

```
public Aluno(String nome,int idade) {
 this.nome = nome;
this.idade = idade;
}
```

e na classe principal chamar:

```
Aluno pedro = new aluno();
```

e inserir os dados na classe principal pelo `Scanner`.

Comment: Não entendi a dúvida, você deve [edit] a pergunta e colocar mais informações relevante para podermos ajudar você. Talvez melhorar o exemplo do que deseja ou só explicar melhor o que precisa.

Comment: Ali no em aluno pedro = new Aluno(); eu preciso passar os dados obrigatoriamente, no exemplo que tinha vista ele defina no scanner da classe principal. como eu posso fazer?

Comment: Você pode dizer se isto esta correto http://pastebin.com/XpEh0Qb0

Comment: pedro, quando pedem pra você tirar uma dúvida aqui nos comentários, você deve **[edit] a pergunta**, não é aporrinhação, é importante mesmo. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código está certo mas poderia fazer melhor:

```
class Aluno {
    String nome;
    int idade;
    public Aluno(String nome, int idade) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.idade = idade;
    }
    public Aluno() { }
}
 
class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        Aluno aluno = new Aluno();
        System.out.println("Qual tu nome");
        aluno.nome = entrada.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Qual tu idade");
        aluno.idade = entrada.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Nome: " + aluno.nome + "\nIdade: " + aluno.idade);   
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/xtXXSa). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/gybiklvm-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Method/ConstructorArgument.java).

Poderia questionar se deveria ter o construtor sem parâmetros. Em códigos reais, talvez não fosse uma boa ideia, não é ideal criar um objeto em um estado inválido. Mas em um exercício não é problema, ainda mais que a solução que estava sendo dada era criar um objeto com estado inválido "à força".

Se não tivesse o construtor com parâmetros, aí não precisaria de construtor algum, afinal, quando não tem construtores, o Java cria um padrão sem parâmetros que não faz inicializações.

Ver mais sobre [construtores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101).

Comment: Exatamente isso que eu estava procurando, agora consegui entender melhor, porém, ainda gostaria de perguntar...Eu não posso usar apenas um construtor com parâmetro? Por que tenho que usar o construtor sem parâmetro também?

Comment: Pode não tê-lo e até eu recomendaria fazer isto. Só mantive para manter a mesma semântica que ele usou. Quando não construtores, o construtor sem parâmetros é criado automaticamente pelo compilador para ter como construir o objeto. Quando se cria um construtor qualquer, ele não é mais necessário e não é criado. Eu acho que ideal mente isto é o desejável porque evita que se crie um objeto com estado potencialmente inválido. Claro que tem situação que isto é desejável, ou o construtor sem parâmetros pode criar um objeto de forma válida (não é o caso). Do jeito acima era melhor não ter mesmo.

Comment: Mas este é só um exercício básico. A intenção não é fazer o mais correto para um sistema real. Ele está só aprendendo conceitos básicos, melhor não complicar. O exercício seria totalmente outro se só tivesse o construtor com argumentos.

Comment: Ah entendi, só perguntei porque estou aprendendo o básico também, e todos os exercícios que estou tentando fazer com um construtor com parâmetro, ele da uma mensagem e me "força" a colocar o construtor sem parâmetro também, nesse caso a mensagem some... rs Mas entendi sim, obrigada @bigown

Comment: Dá que mensagem? Não é para ser obrigatório. Até porque se fosse, o compilador poderia resolver isto.

Comment: Entendi... Então, tenho uma classe principal chamada Principal5 e uma classe chamada Calculadora, na Calculadora eu criei um construtor com parâmetros. E quando eu vou instanciar a classe Calculadora na classe principal, na linha da instância, aparece "Criar construtor "Calculadora()" em principal5.Calculadora" E o projeto fica com um icone de erro no Principal5.java

Comment: Isso deve ser coisa ruim do IDE que está usando. O ideal seria desabilitar isto.

Comment: Ah entendi, vou desabilitar aqui então. Obrigada.